# Loop through multidimensional array and echo values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that I would like to loop through and print the values that are stored in the array. This is the end result I am looking to achieve

```
{ "lat": 52.4469601, "lon": -1.93685532},
{ "lat": 52.44332417, "lon": -1.9426918},
{ "lat": 52.43987106, "lon": -1.9329071}
```

How would I go about printing the values like this? Currently this is how I am printing the whole array:

```
$enc = 'NTIuNDQ2OTYwMSwtMS45MzY4NTUzMnw1Mi40NDMzMjQxNywtMS45NDI2OTE4fDUyLjQzOTg3MTA2LC0xLjkzMjkwNzF8NTIuNDQ1NDk1MywtMS45MjU4MjYwN3w';

$decoded = base64_decode($enc);

$trim = trim($decoded, '|');
$data = explode('|', $decoded);
$out = array();
$step = 0;
$last = count($data);
$last--;

foreach( $data as $key => $item ) {
    foreach (explode(',', $item) as $value) {
        $out[$key][] = $value;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $out );
echo "</pre>";
```

And the output looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 52.4469601
            [1] => -1.93685532
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 52.44332417
            [1] => -1.9426918
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 52.43987106
            [1] => -1.9329071
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 52.4454953
            [1] => -1.92582607
        )

)
```

Comment: I suppose the last code is how your array is built initialy right?

Comment: print input arr

Comment: @JuOliveira yes that is how the array is built :)

Comment: use json_encode if you want it to look like a json or build the strings yourself

Comment: instead of print_r use echo json_encode($out); ?

Comment: json_encode is your friend

Comment: Show the original string or better the raw data.

Comment: @Ann-SophieAngermüller yes that what I was looking for - can't believe I didn't think of that to start with

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte added to the post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is exported always with  "lat" and "lon" pairs then you can do this:

```
foreach( $data as $key => $item ) {
    $lat = true;
    foreach (explode(',', $item) as $value) {
        if($lat == true){
            $out[$key]["lat"] = $value;
            $lat = false;
        } else {
            $out[$key]["lon"] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome that was pretty much what I was looking for - along with adding `json_encode` like @Ann-SophieAngermüller and @AlexOdenthal suggest worked fine

Answer (score 0):

An other way to do it using a stream approach:

```
$enc = 'NTIuNDQ2OTYwMSwtMS45MzY4NTUzMnw1Mi40NDMzMjQxNywtMS45NDI2OTE4fDUyLjQzOTg3MTA2LC0xLjkzMjkwNzF8NTIuNDQ1NDk1MywtMS45MjU4MjYwN3w';

$handle = fopen("data:text/plain;base64,$enc", 'r');

$res = [];    

while ( false !== $rec = stream_get_line($handle, 0, '|') ) {
     $res[] = array_combine(['lat', 'lon'], str_getcsv($rec));
}

echo json_encode($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$enc = 'NTIuNDQ2OTYwMSwtMS45MzY4NTUzMnw1Mi40NDMzMjQxNywtMS45NDI2OTE4fDUyLjQzOTg3MTA2LC0xLjkzMjkwNzF8NTIuNDQ1NDk1MywtMS45MjU4MjYwN3w';

$decodedArr = explode('|', base64_decode($enc));

$latLong = [];
foreach ($decodedArr as $latLongStr) {
    if (!$latLongStr) {
        continue;
    }

    $temp = explode(',', $latLongStr);

    $latLong[] = ['lat' => $temp[0], 'lon' => $temp[1]];
}

echo json_encode($latLong);
```

Output

```
[{"lat":"52.4469601","lon":"-1.93685532"},{"lat":"52.44332417","lon":"-1.9426918"},{"lat":"52.43987106","lon":"-1.9329071"},{"lat":"52.4454953","lon":"-1.92582607"}]
```